# Tornado: Identify / track connections of websockets?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have a basic Tornado websocket test:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message

    def on_close(self):
      print 'connection closed'


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I want to be able to handle multiple connections (which it seems to do already) but also to be able to reference other connections. I don't see a way to identify and keep track of individual connections, just to be able to handle events on connection open, receipt of messages, and connection close.

[Edit]
Thought of creating a dict where the key is the Sec-websocket-key and and the value is the WSHandler object... thoughts? I'm not sure how dependable Sec-websocket-key is to be unique.

Comment: As far as I know, there is a single WSHandler instance per connection will be created. So, WSHandlers are basically only connection interfaces. May be you want to add some message-processing engine atop of networking for example like http://code.google.com/p/pyscxml/ ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The simplest method is just to keep a list or dict of WSHandler instances:

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    clients = []

    def open(self):
        self.clients.append(self)
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message

    def on_close(self):
        self.clients.remove(self)
        print 'closed connection'
```

If you want to identify connections, e.g. by user, you'll probably have to send that information over the socket.

Comment: `If you want to identify connections, e.g. by user, you'll probably have to send that information over the socket.`. I don't get what you mean here? How to identify a connection by the user?

Comment: One way (for example) would be to send the session id over the socket, handle it in `on_message`, and store it on the `WSHandler` instance (or wherever).

Comment: @ColeMaclean great answer! But what if in a system with multiple users, I want to send data received from one websocket client(browser1) who also updated a database, and pass that data to another client(browser2)?

Comment: @direwolf7 You need to handle all that (or preferably call something else that does) in `on_message`

Comment: I think it's more proper to use a set here instead of a list, to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 21):

Cole Maclean asnwer is good as simple solution, when you just need list of all connections. 
However, if you want something more complex, that can be monitored outside of `WSHandler` instance - be brave do it like this:

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self):
        self.id = uuid.uuid4()
        external_storage[self.id] = {'id':self.id}
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")

    def on_message(self, message):
        #Some message parsing here
        if message.type == 'set_group':
           external_storage[self.id]['group'] = message.group
        print 'message received %s' % message

    def on_close(self):
        external_storage.remove(self.id)
        print 'closed connection'
```

Comment: Cole's answer does what I need, but I'll keep yours in mind if I do need more control outside of the WSHandler itself. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Nikolay, really good answer Nikolay, very nice idea to keep track of users without letting them send who they are, you can easily identify them and send a message/close the connection accordingly ... Good job :)). usuallly the storage of such type of information is done with Redis.

Comment: Definitely a solid way to handle this scenario.

Comment: Can I actually store the handler object in external cache like memcached? I think object itself can be serialised however it's associated with the connect, I'm not sure that will be lost or not ...

Comment: What if I have multiple tornado servers? How can I communicate between them and clients (browsers)?

Comment: @madzohan, you must broadcast message between backends - they will broadcast it to clients. How to sync backends - another question.

Answer (score 1):

If your users have an access token, this can be appended to your websocket endpoint, say, and fetched in initialising your socket even before it's opened (but please work over SSL).

If an access token is not available, either because the user hasn't supplied one or the token they supplied has expired, the user is not authenticated and you will kill the socket at the earliest opportunity.

However you do this, the access token should be associated to a user who will have an identifier and that identifier can then be tied to the socket even before it has been opened. The identifier can serve as a dictionary key whose value is a set of sockets tied to this user.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by checking the origin of the conexion. So, overrriding the method `def check_origin(self, origin)` may help. For example:

```
clients = {}

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):


    def check_origin(self, origin): 

        clients[origin] = self
        print(clients)
        return True
```